# javascript SQLITE_BUSY: database is locked, sql: insert into "users"

Tags: javascript, sqlite, bcrypt

I am working on a 'sign up' page and having trouble with sqlite.

I am using express, bcrypt-nodejs, bookself.js for sqlite. getting an error saying database is lock. any workaround for this? appreciated. below is the code for the part.

```
app.post('/signup', function(req, res){
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  bcrypt.hash(password, null, null, function(err, hash){
    new User({'username': username, 'password': hash})
      .save()
      .then(function(){
        console.log('Successfully added a user');
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        throw err;
      });
  });
  res.render('login');
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was that you have the ".sqlite" file opened by other editors or SQLite Clients while interacting with SQLite programmatically.

Make sure the .sqlite file is not opened/used by any other application before running/testing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Also works, when you kill the running port.

For ubuntu Use:

```
'sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:<POOR_NUMBER>`'
```